# Problems on Hardy's Introduction to Divergent Series

Tags: complex-analysis

In the introduction to Hardy's last work, "Divergent Series", he writes that $$\frac{1}{1-e^{ix}}$$ generates this sort of power series: $$1+ e^{ix} + e^{2ix} + \ldots $$ According to (1.2.2) of the introduction, this series converges to $\frac{i}{2}+ \frac{i}{2}\cot(x/2)$. If this be true, wouldn't taking the integral of this function three times give us a closed form for $\zeta(3)$?

Comment: Can you give more details as to why you think is true?

Comment: I had to take Hardy on faith on that one.

Comment: From integrating the power-series one does get this (forgetting about convergence for now) since $\int e^{ikx} dx = \frac{1}{ik}e^{ikx}$ so integrate three times gives $\frac{i}{k^3}e^{ikx}$ and evaluating at zero gives a term that is $\sum \frac{i}{k^3} = i\zeta(3)$

Comment: I believe $\frac{1}{1-e^{ix}}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\cot\frac{x}{2}$, but why do you believe integrating 3 times would give a closed form for $\zeta (3)$?

Comment: @ winther....I see now

Comment: It depends what one means by closed form. I guess OP means an integral representation of $\zeta(3)$ ?!

Comment: Because once integrated three times, before plugging in x=pi, I substituted (cosx +isinx) for (e^ix). Then, I used De Moivre's theorem. Finally I plug in x=pi. All the sine functions of the series cancel out leaving the cosine functions.

Comment: Of course $\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-inx}$ does not converge at $x=0$.

Comment: Dear @Winther: Thank you. You just gave me an idea. Taking this into consideration with the first question I posted, the function should be z(3) = -(e^(inx))/(n^3) with n equaling 1,2... and x= pi.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. The closed function for zeta(3)= ((-1)^(n))*(e^(inx))/(n^3)  with x=pi